# "I've been loving you" is not a formal English

Tags: grammar, present-participles, present-continuous

The phrase *I've been loving you* is not formal English.

Or so I'm told. I can't figure out what is wrong, though, please someone kindly explain.

I did google and found on WordReference the thread: [Since I've been loving you/Since I've loved](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/since-ive-been-loving-you-since-ive-loved-you.2778264/)

The problem is I don't even understand why 'loving' (Post #3) is considered incorrect.

> Spot on, Alex! The point here is that "love" is a stative verb. If you look at the British Council Learn English site here, you'll see that stative verbs are "not usually used in the continuous form, even when we are talking about temporary situations or states ..."

English is not my native language.

Comment: In what formal context are you writing?

Comment: These are song lyrics.  Led Zeppelin, apparently.

Comment: Related: [“I'm lovin' it”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/im-lovin-it) and [Verbs not normally used in the present continuous](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/237282/verbs-not-normally-used-in-the-present-continuous)

Comment: Sometime, somebody said that so-called stative verbs weren't (usually)  used in the progressive. And people have been repeating that ever since. But it doesn't describe how English actually works. And your clause is a good example. *I've been loving you* is fine. Even *I've been being you* is fine. As for the definition of  formal English, that is ambiguous.

Comment: I think it really depends on what you are trying to say. Context is key here.

Answer (score 1):

To the extent that it's wrong, it's because others consider *love* to be a [stative verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stative_verb) like *be* or *have*. To the extent you disagree, you're treating it as an active or dynamic verb.

Comment: How is anyone treating it like a dynamic verb? Isn't rather that the idea that stative verbs can't be in the progressive is insupportable? Or also that the whole concept of stative vs dynamic verbs needs jettisoning? *I'm having a hard time seeing why this sentence is wrong: he's being a hero by not standing by doing nothing.* In fact almost every single so called stative verb can be used in the progressive.

Comment: @Clare I know with that attitude you're not likely to, but **you're welcome to reverse your vote**, given that I explicitly mentioned **both** that people like you exist who feel like special snowflakes for forming sentences like *I've been loving you* and *I've been having my house for many years* **and** why other people might disagree.

Comment: Even if *you* disagree with *them*, that has no bearing on my answer being correct as far as why *they* told *him* it was "incorrect".

Comment: Sorry I'm still missing something definitely. How does one determine it's a stative verb? Is it something similar to that of regular and irregular verb? It's the first time I hear about stative verb - I've been oblivious all along.

Comment: @Ily, I know with that attitude you're not likely to, and you're welcome to change your mind; doubly so since no evidence mentioned either that people exist who feel like special snowflakes for forming sentences such as *I’ve been loving you* or *I’ve been having my house for many years*

Your example sentences are not comparable.

Will you explain what you see as wrong with, for instance, *I’ve been loving you since we met, 30 years ago*?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Obviously native speakers can form such good sentences in good faith, but besides being needlessly verbose and clunky to get the same point across as *I've loved you since we met* or *I've been in love with you since we met*, your phrasing connotes that one has been in a physical act of love for thirty years. It sounds more exhausting than pleasant or flattering.

Comment: @trashcanbin You can tell from the snark and venom that some native speakers are very defensive about whether they exist or not. Just like how noncount nouns (e.g., *water*) can become countable in certain circumstances (*We'd just like three waters while we look at the menu, thanks*), they're not wrong that people can invent a continuous sense of almost anything. But...

Comment: ...it's a helpful way of thinking about how English usually treats words like *be* and *have* (as *possess* but not *consume*) that describe a state of being instead of an action. The difference can be especially confusing to ESL speakers, who sometimes use *being* in uncomfortable ways (like Mr Goodwin just did). There's more at the Wikipedia entry I linked and elsewhere around the net (including here at StackExchange). Just keep the unpleasant editors above in mind: some people strongly dispute the idea's relevance or even existence.

Comment: @Ily It matters not at all whether anything is needlessly verbose or clunky to get the same point across as *I've loved you since we met* or *I've been in love with you since we met*; the OQ was whether the phrase *I've been loving you* is formal English.  

*I've been loving you* does not connote that one has been in a physical act of love, nor anything like it. I hadn’t noticed this before but that claim and the phrase *(anyone) can form such good sentences in good faith* indicates English isn’t your first language… *more*

Comment: @Ily Whether *love* is a stative verb, or the British Council’s Learn English site says *stative verbs aren’t usually used in the continuous form*, neither would make *I’ve been loving you* not formal English.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Yes, yes, yes, and I can and have disparaged you for your inability to speak fluent native English as well. Do we have to keep this up until a moderator intervenes? or **can you f--- off** (look, ma! native English!) **and do something useful** like providing *your own answer* to this question, instead of just harassing the people who already provided correct answers to it?

Answer (score 0):

We sometimes say something like "the word 'love' is a verb". But this is at best a shorthand, at worst a misunderstanding. "Verb" is a part of a sentence, and until a word is *used*, it doesn't become a verb, noun or any other part of speech.

This is relevant since it is the use of the word that determines which part of speech it is. Now the word "love" when used in a sentence "I love chips" is indicating a state. In this way it differs in meaning from "I eat chips", which indicates an action. This is a semantic difference, not a grammatical one.

Now the present continuous can be formed, and it indicates a continuous or repeated action. "I am eating chips" is a continuous action. But *semantically* "I am loving chips" is slightly odd. It is odd in the same way that "Green ideas sleep furiously" is odd. The grammar is fine, but the meanings jar.

We interpret "I am loving chips" to mean that the state is temporary. That is an odd idea. More natural would be "I'm loving these chips", because it is understood that after they are eaten they are no longer loved.

However, in formal contexts we want to avoid this kind of semantic oddness. And we usually can, for example the word "enjoy" can be used to indicate a state or an action, and so "I am enjoying chips" doesn't cause problems.

Over time, such differences in meaning can become differences in grammar. Ancient Indo-European had different grammar for "things that are alive" and "Things that are not alive". This was based on meaning. Over time this became fixed as the grammatical genders "masculine/feminine" and "Neuter", that anyone learning French, Spanish or German (for example) will know.

So when someone writes "I have been loving you", the word "love" is coerced from its usual meaning of indicating a state, to indicating a temporary but continuous action. As such it is rather dramatic! The speaker is saying that their love is not permanent. As such it is acceptable if that is the meaning that is intended.